# HTTPS giving 404 not found error

Tags: php, apache, ssl, google-cloud-platform, bitnami

I have install the SSL certification on my bitnami google cloud hosting.
certificate has been property installed and even

I can access :

```
https://domain.com
```

but when I try to access

```
https://domain.com/xyz
```

> its giving me 404 not found error

Below is my `binami.conf` file

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
  SSLEngine on
  SSLCertificateFile "/opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/server.crt"
  SSLCertificateKeyFile "/opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/server.key"

  DocumentRoot "/opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/domain/public/"
  <Directory "/opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/htdocs/domain/public/">
    Options FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AddLanguage en en
    LanguagePriority en
    ForceLanguagePriority Prefer Fallback

    AllowOverride All
    <IfVersion < 2.3 >
      Order allow,deny
      Allow from all
    </IfVersion>
    <IfVersion >= 2.3 >
      Require all granted
    </IfVersion>
  </Directory>

  # Error Documents
  ErrorDocument 503 /503.html

  # Bitnami applications installed with a prefix URL (default)
  Include "/opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/bitnami/bitnami-apps-prefix.conf"
</VirtualHost>
```

Can anyone please help me, what went wrong
For more information
Am using google cloud platform with Bitnami LAMP stack

Comment: but can you access `http://domain.com/xyz` that is the question, for example is that a valid url, if it's not SSL makes no difference.

Comment: Yes, its a valid URL and everything is running find when I use the website without https

Comment: We would really need to see `.conf`  file for `<VirtualHost *:80>`, there is probably some rewriting there that is missing on https site.

Answer (score 1):

In the `<VirtualHost _default_ *:80>`, you are setting:

```
DocumentRoot "/opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/domainDIR/public/"
```

However, in the `<VirtualHost *:443>`, you are setting:

```
DocumentRoot "/opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/domain/public/"
```

Where is your web application located? Both paths should be the same one.

Answer (score 0):

@DusanBajic

```
<VirtualHost _default_ *:80>
  DocumentRoot "/opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/domainDIR/public/"
  <Directory "/opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/domainDIR/public/">
    Options FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AddLanguage en en
    LanguagePriority en
    ForceLanguagePriority Prefer Fallback
    AllowOverride All
    <IfVersion < 2.3 >
      Order allow,deny
      Allow from all
    </IfVersion>
    <IfVersion >= 2.3 >
      Require all granted
    </IfVersion>
  </Directory>
  # Error Documents
  ErrorDocument 503 /503.html
  Include "/opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/bitnami/bitnami-apps-prefix.conf"
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just guessing but I think that **bitnami.conf** should only have this for the  ssl part.

```
# Default SSL Virtual Host configuration.

<IfModule !ssl_module>
  LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so
</IfModule>

Listen 443
SSLProtocol all -SSLv2 -SSLv3
SSLHonorCipherOrder on
SSLCipherSuite "EECDH+ECDSA+AESGCM EECDH+aRSA+AESGCM EECDH+ECDSA+SHA384 EECDH+ECDSA+SHA256 EECDH+aRSA+SHA384 EECDH+aRSA+SHA256 EECDH !aNULL !eNULL !LOW !3DES !MD5 !EXP !PSK !SRP !DSS !EDH !RC4"
SSLPassPhraseDialog  builtin
SSLSessionCache "shmcb:/opt/bitnami/apache2/logs/ssl_scache(512000)"
SSLSessionCacheTimeout  300

<VirtualHost _default_:443>
  DocumentRoot "/opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs"
  SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile "/opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/server.crt"
SSLCertificateKeyFile "/opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/server.key"

  <Directory "/opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs">
    Options FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AddLanguage en en
    LanguagePriority en
    ForceLanguagePriority Prefer Fallback

    AllowOverride All
    <IfVersion < 2.3 >
      Order allow,deny                          
      Allow from all
    </IfVersion>
    <IfVersion >= 2.3 >
      Require all granted
    </IfVersion>
  </Directory>

  # Error Documents
  ErrorDocument 503 /503.html

  # Bitnami applications installed with a prefix URL (default)
  Include "/opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/bitnami/bitnami-apps-prefix.conf"
</VirtualHost>

# Bitnami applications that uses virtual host configuration
Include "/opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/bitnami/bitnami-apps-vhosts.conf"
```

and you should put your `<VirtualHost *:443>` code from above (top) into the **/extras/httpd-ssl.conf** file.

Then restart apache via Putty (or whatever you use)

sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh restart apache

I'll try to test it sometime this week and edit as necessary ( 8^{D=

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, `404 NOT FOUND` can be served from 1 of 2 places in this situation.  The Apache server may be responding with `404` or the request received by Apache is routed to the application and the application serves the `404`.

If the application were serving `404 NOT FOUND`, as the application owner, one could presumably log every request to see this occur.  As you've not mentioned the application much at all, we must assume this is not the source and investigate the Apache server.

The configurations you've provided for both HTTP (**:80**) and HTTPS (**:443**) serve static resources with [`<Directory "">`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#directory).  However, the paths to both directory and `DocumentRoot` are different between HTTP and HTTPS as mentioned by @Juan.

`"/opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/domainDIR/public/"` != `"/opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/domain/public/"`

If you do not have 2 different directories for serving static resources based on HTTP(S), then this is the most likely cause of the `404`.  Apache cannot find `"/opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/domain/public/"` when serving over HTTPS.

***Note that at present, the Bitnami LAMP image on Google Cloud [deploys with Apache 2.4.25](https://console.cloud.google.com/launcher/details/bitnami-launchpad/lampstack) and thus shouldn't ever meet the `<IfVersion < 2.3>` criteria.  It's safe to keep though if using the same configuration elsewhere.***